how to gif animated Image Crop in android?
I am using Ucrop, an image cropping library, for image cropping.
When running the ucrop library, the image does not move. Could it be a problem with the library itself? If you use ucrop, please let me know.
However, animated photos made up of gif and webP files do not work with image cropping. Is there a way to solve this problem?
my Crop code
fun callCrop(i: Int, imageUri: Uri) {
        var uCrop: UCrop? = null; 
        val options: UCrop.Options = UCrop.Options();
        //options.setCompressionQuality(50)
        options.setAspectRatioOptions(1,
            AspectRatio("4:5", 4f, 5f),
            AspectRatio("1x1", 1f, 1f),
            AspectRatio("16x9", 16f, 9f))


        try  {
            uCrop = UCrop.of(imageUri, Uri.fromFile(createImageFile()))
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        uCrop?.withOptions(options)
        uCrop?.start(requireActivity())
    }

    private fun createImageFile() :File {
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(Date())
        val tempImg: String = "temp_" + timeStamp + ""
        val storageDir: File = File("${requireActivity().filesDir}/mz/")
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            storageDir.mkdirs();
        }

        val image: File = File.createTempFile(tempImg, ".webp", storageDir)
        return image

    }

    fun showImages() {
        val imageResponses = ArrayList<ImageData>()
        for (img in cropedUris) {
            imageResponses.add(ImageData(0L, img.path!!))
        }

    

    communityWriteAddImgListRecyclerViewAdapter.addAllImg(imageResponses)
            communityWriteAddImgListRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }


if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {
            val resultUri: Uri? = UCrop.getOutput(data!!)

            communityWriteFragment.cropedUris.add(resultUri!!)
            communityWriteFragment.cropCount++
            if (communityWriteFragment.cropCount == communityWriteFragment.imageUris.size) {
                communityWriteFragment.showImages()
            } else {
                communityWriteFragment.callCrop(communityWriteFragment.cropCount, communityWriteFragment.imageUris.get(communityWriteFragment.cropCount))
            }
        }

